# What is the difference between NP hard and NP complete?

Tags: complexity-theory

[What is the definition of P, NP, NP-complete and NP-hard?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard)

here is a good answer but it really doesn't answer mym question.

> np-hard-: a problem A is NP hard if for all B$\in$NP, B is polynomial time reducible to A.(i.e A is easier than B). Then why is A called NP Hard? It should be called NP easy problem? Isn't it?

> np complete-: A problem is NP complete if problem is in both NP and NP hard.

SO basically np complete=np hard. What is the difference between np hard and np complete?

Answer (score 2):

So I got it. NP hard problem is not necessarily in NP. That's the difference.